# Safe strategy for saving new entries in a hibernate web app?

Tags: hibernate

I have a session-per-request type of a web application. On every request it saves information about user accessing resources. The table for this information has a composite id consisting of the user id and the resource id. I want to keep information only from the last access.

In rare occations (easy to reproduce with code changes) I get `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`: Duplicate entry errors when two different transactions are trying to insert with the same composite id. My code tries to check if the entry is already found in the database and then inserts it if it's not and otherwise updates.

My question is the following: **How do I safely save new entries?**

Comment: 1. You need to merge your entities with every request's session
2. If you have long time "request flow", you should make custom conversation scope for your controller beans and store all data there. And persist in hibernate only at conversation finish (e.g. on Save or Finish button pressed)

Comment: I might be misinformed but I don't think merge will make a difference when two concurrent requests are being handled and both try to insert data.

Comment: two concurrent requests = two hibernate sessions. every session can insert data. its not problem.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with just inserting but inserting with same primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following hibernate property.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">8</property>
```

- 1: READ UNCOMMITTED
- 2: READ COMMITTED
- 4: REPEATABLE READ
- 8: SERIALIZABLE

More Info is [here](https://dzone.com/articles/beginners-guide-transaction).

By making the above change, there will be a performance impact.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does the merge handle two concurrent data inserts?

Comment: @anssias : Although you think SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException occurs because of concurrent reqeusts, I think it is not the case here. Did you try my solution ? By the way, did you change any locking properties in DB ?

Comment: @anssias: Did you try? what is the result?

Comment: Yes I tried and I ran into the same problem. I ended up saving the information in a different transaction and ignore errors on duplicate entries. This only happens if the user has not accessed the resource and somehow manages to access it with two requests at the same time.

Comment: @anssias : I changed my answer. This should work. Try and let me know. :)

Comment: Much appreciated but I don't think it's a good solution to set the isolation level to serializable for general read operations. I think the problem lies in poor design choices.